# How to wait for a element to contain a specific attribute through Selenium and WebDriverWait?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have a selenium question if someone could help. I need to get into a URL page where initially a node on that page is in the "registered" status, and X amount of seconds later, its status will dynamically changed to "ready" status. And until its status has moved to "ready' status, I may continue the next steps during selenium execution. 
Here is the html code of the initial code,

```
<div class="icon-holder pull-left" action = "select-device" sn="FX0071234" status = "in_stock">
   <i class = "...">...</i>
   <div class="model-holder">
       <span class="model-registered">200K</span>
   </div>
   <div class="active-holder">...</div>
</div>
```

And here is the updated html code after X amount of seconds,

```
<div class="icon-holder pull-left" action = "select-device" sn="FX0071234" status = "discovered">
   <i class = "...">...</i>
   <div class="model-holder">
       <span class="model-ready">200K</span>
   </div>
   <div class="active-holder">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to new a WebDriverWait() Obj to wait for the change happens. Here is my code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(
                By.xpath("//span[@class = 'model-registered' and text() = '200K']"), "class", "model-ready"));
```

But during my selenium run-time, this piece of code never works, it exists instantly. Any ideas what could be wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait for the element to be changed to **ready** status you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

```
boolean status = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(By.xpath("//div[@class='model-holder']/span[contains(.,'200K')]"), "class", "model-ready"));
```

Comment: This is a better solution comparing to my original one. I guess mine "confuses"  the script.

Comment: @user3595231 Glad to be able to help you !!! Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benifit of the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly wait for element with class "model-ready" to exists. Here's the code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(
            By.xpath("//span[@class = 'model-ready' and text() = '200K']")));
```

Let me know if this doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Use FluentWait to wait until status changes to 'Ready'.

```
 Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(webDriver)
.withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // set the timeout
.pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // set the interval. Checks every 2sec's for the element status 'ready'

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() { 
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) { 
return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'model-ready' and text() = '200K']")); 
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the method `waitForAttributeMatchesRegex` to wait for the targeting attribute until it matches some specific pattern.

Something like this:
`webElement.waitForAttributeMatchesRegex(attribute, regex);`