# C#: Wait for element to contain specific attribute in Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am waiting for an element Attribute `aria-sort` to equal "`descending`".

Currently using C# Selenium webdriver. How do I conduct this? I do not see AttributeContains in Visual Studio.

[How to wait for a element to contain a specific attribute through Selenium and WebDriverWait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257286/how-to-wait-for-a-element-to-contain-a-specific-attribute-through-selenium-and-w)

```
boolean status = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(By.xpath("//div[@class='model-holder']/span[contains(.,'200K')]"), "class", "model-ready"));
```

Comment: You may need to create your own ExpectedCondition for this.  See the answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048105/expectedcondition-method-attributecontains-for-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to the way presented in the post you have mentioned in your question you can also do the following:
Let's say that element can be uniquely located by the following XPath `//tag[@class='theClass']`
So when this element will have `aria-sort` attribute equals to `descending`, then this element can be located by this XPath:  `//tag[@class='theClass' and(@aria-sort='descending')]`
So you can simply use regular `ElementExists` `ExpectedConditions` as following:

```
boolean status = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.xpath("//tag[@class='theClass' and(@aria-sort='descending')]"));
```

However this approach is not really good since it is not general enough, so it's much better to create custom `ExpectedConditions` according to the element attribute as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048105/expectedcondition-method-attributecontains-for-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I have Written an extension method in C# Selenium , this will help to wait until a particular element / attribute is visible.

Call This method like : WaitUntilElementIsVisible(driver, By.Id("DemoId"));  // example

```
public static bool WaitUntilElementIsVisible(IWebDriver browser, By by)
{
            int attemptToFindElement = 0;
            bool elementFound = false;
            IWebElement elementIdentifier = null;
            do
            {
                attemptToFindElement++;
                try
                {
                    elementIdentifier = browser.FindWebElement(by);
                    elementFound = (elementIdentifier.Displayed && elementIdentifier.Enabled) ? true : false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    elementFound = false;
                }

            }
            while (elementFound == false && attemptToFindElement < 100);

            return elementFound;
}
```